# Этимология слов «качество» и «количество»

Tags: этимология, семантика

Правда ли, что слова *качество* и *количество* произошли от праформ *как* и *сколько* соответственно?

Answer (score 4):

[Этимологический словарь Крылова](https://gufo.me/dict/krylov/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)

**Количество**

> Заимствование из церковнославянского, где кояикий – "сколький, который
>   по счету" образовано err коли, в свою очередь образованного от
>   местоименного ко и частицы лы.

(Тут возможны ошибки конвертанции, но в славянстве не сомневается никто.)

---

Этимологический словарь  Шанского и Бобровой

> Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз., где количьство — словообразовательная калька
>   греч. posotēs, суф. производного от posos «сколько»: pos- — колич-,
>   -otes — -ество. Общеслав. коликыи — суф. образование (ср. великий) от коль, см. сколько.
>
> ---

Смотрим [сколько](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Skolko-4048.html):

> Искон. Сращение предлога с в значении «приблизительно» (ср. с дом) и
>   колико «сколько», образованного с помощью суф. -к- от коли. Ср.
>   столько, толика.
>
> ---

У [Фасмера](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) немного иначе:

> Происходит от церк.-слав. количьство, от коли́кий, далее из праслав.,
>   от кот. в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. колико (др.-греч. πόσον),
>   русск. сколько, укр. коли́ко, стар., кíлько, болг. ко́лко, сербохорв.
>   ко̀лик, ко̏лико, словенск. kólik, kóliko, чешск. kolik «сколько»,
>   словацк. kоľkо, в.-луж. kélko, н.-луж. keliko, польск. kilka, диал.
>   kielka «несколько, некоторые».

У него же

**качество**

> Происходит от русск.-церк.-слав. качьство (др.-греч. ποιότης). От как,
>   какой.

Comment: «Этимологический словарь Крылова» — c сайта, знаменитого своими опечатками, между прочим. «Кояикий» и «err»!