# Союз "коли" и слово "количество" имеют общий исторический корень или нет?

Tags: этимология

Союз ***"КОЛИ"*** — это  разговорный вариант союза ***ЕСЛИ***, а союз ***"КОЛЬ СКОРО"*** из книжной лексики. Могут они иметь общий исторический корень со словом **"количество"** или это ошибочное мнение?

Что же это за корень ***КОЛ***, где его можно встретить **в современном языке?**

Большой толковый словарь

**КОЛИ; КОЛИ; КОЛЬ, союз.** (в начале придат. условн., выражающего реально возможное условие). **Нар.-разг. В том случае, когда; если.** * Коль ты старый человек, Дядей будешь нам навек. Коли парень ты румяный, Братец будешь нам названый (Пушкин). Коль любить, так без рассудку (А.К. Толстой). **Коль скоро, союз. Книжн.** Если; раз уж. Коль скоро этот проект получил одобрение конкурсной комиссии, он должен быть реализован.

Comment: Имеют: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448161/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE

Comment: Спасибо, эти словари  я читала, и в моем ответе эта информация есть.  Обсуждалась связь: коли  (союз) и  слова около, сколько, коло как круг.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, Шарон! И на ваши ответы ещё будут давать ссылки))

Comment: Зачем же на меня?)) Я только Черных пересказываю, поэтому на него.  А от себя – ни-ни! Кстати, и-е корень ko без форманта l так и не нашли, только kol и  kеl.  А  ko – местоименный корень для kъto, kolъ и koli.

Comment: «Зачем же на меня?)) Я только Черных пересказываю, поэтому на него» — Значит, будут давать ссылки на ваши ответы, где вы пересказываете Черныха)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Колобродить — ходить по кругу. **Кол** = круг (*лошадь ходит на колу, на приколе*). «Кто скорее из нас обежит около моря...» (здесь о**кол**о = вокруг).

Круг лиц, круг знакомств, круг интересов, — всё это имеет количественную составляющую. Всё что-либо рядом и вне круга находящееся, — о**кол**о или вблизи, — с некоторой поправкой на точность (*в том случае, когда; если*), можно определить лишь примерно: нас**кол**ько возможно.

Comment: Спасибо (голос от меня), про около поняла  https://lexicography.online/etymology/о/около.  Вы считаете, что круг и сколько - однокоренные?

Comment: Коли парень ты румяный, Братец будешь нам названый. Насколько румяный?  Иди насколько скоро румяный?

Comment: Похоже, хорошо СНГ встретили... Ключевое слово *парень*: «коли (*если*) парень».

Comment: С точки зрения семантики ваш ответ мне понтен, не хватило только обоснования в этимологических словарях. Круг действительно по смыслу близок к словам "сколько" и "коли" (= если). Поэтому я принимаю ваш ответ, который наилучшим образом помог мне разобраться в теме на данном этапе.

Comment: Можно было бы признать и существование (наряду с *кол*) корня **ко**.  Как известно, приставки такой нет, но слова, с **ко** начинающиеся, встречаются часто: кожа, кофта, кора... И со схожим смыслом «около и вплотную; по контуру».

Comment: Со словарем приходится работать так. Какое слово предположительно может содержать и.-е. корень ко? Контур? Начинаешь искать, а там контур происходит от франц. contour, из ср.-лат. contornare «огибать». Приставка con  со значением "вместе, рядом"  и  и.-е. корень ter- «тереть». Не тот корень.

Comment: Опять не то слово принимаете за ключевое. Праздник продолжается. Часто слышимое уточнение «не когда, а если» хорошо показывает разницу в смыслах: *коли* (т.е. «когда») *парень* — совсем не *если парень*.

Comment: Праздник  — это прекрасно) Жаль, что никто не веселится вместе с нами.  Уж очень у вас тонкие намеки) Буратино вот выражают свою мысль однозначно (румяный или полурумяный), да и то не многие понимают.

Answer (score 1):

Кол - круг, количество, круглая сумма, что-то полное и весомое, что-то вместе, всё.

Коли так - мол, раз так, если это вся история, вся ситуация, весь контекст, если не скрываешь, то  можно сделать вывод и поступить так-то.

Коли парень ты румяный - если ты парень полностью, по-настоящему, румяный, а не полурумяный, если весь ты румяный.

А может, кол и колоть - делать дыру. То есть кол - это пустой круг, недостача. Сколько - какое что-то требуется.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за внимание к теме. Значит, полурумяный, да?  Но  здесь одним полурумяным братцем не обойдешься — у нас «серьезный» этимологический разговор.  И тогда к вам вопросы:  1)  Коли  и насколько — однокоренные?   2)  Коло (круг) и насколько — однокоренные?  Это (2) можно доказать? Я не совсем поняла вашу точку зрения. Из словаря: КОЛИ. Нар.-разг. В том случае, когда; если.

Comment: @Sharon насколько - это на сколько, только наречие, потому слитно пишется с предлогом. То есть слово "сколько". Приходит кто-то просить, что просит? то что ему "надо", какое-то кол+ичество. То есть если он получит столько(с толикой, то есть до края, теликос - это край, наполнит до края) то он получит целый, скажем, мешок, один мешок. То есть слова один-раз-кол-полный - это синонимы одного и того же понятия полного - которое может стать целым. Круг вообще это изначально кольцо - то есть то, что сейчас называется окружность, обод, обвод. Вокруг есть, а внутри полый.

Comment: Наверное поэтому колобродить - ходить бесцельно. без возможности попасть в центр круга может, где центр это середина и целое. Наверное однокоренные все: и кол, и коли, и сколько, и количество. Количество - это сколько тебе не хватает. Сколько надо. То есть сколько у тебя нет. Некое пустое, то что можно наполнить до целого. Условие, условное что-то. Если.

Comment: Сложные семантические взаимосвязи, да.   Мы любим оценки и сравнения,  как бы рисуем круг близости чего-то к чему-то. Но этимология  – наука точная, я все о словаре думаю. Вот Черных остановился на том, что количество – это калька с древнегреческого сколь. Но про круг kolo ничего не сказано. Где к нему мостик?

Comment: @Sharon а что такое сколь? сколь малый? в таком смысле?

Comment: У Черных:  Слово сколько: др.-рус. колико, и.-е. местоименный корень ko, как в о.-с. kъto — который, о.-с. формы kolъ и koli. Что такое местоименный корень? Он не называет, а  только указывает.

Comment: @Sharon может который вроде?

Comment: Остается нерешенной задача. Есть и.-е. МЕСТОИМЕННЫЙ корень  ko  (о.-с. kъto — который, о.-с. формы kolъ и koli — сколько). Есть   и.- е. корни:  kol — вращаться ( о.-с. kolo — круг) и  kel — бить, ударять (о.-с. основа kolti). — Но нет  и.- е. корня ko (не местоименного).  В каких словах ее искать?

Answer (score 0):

Я приведу найденный  **[материал из Сети](https://poseidon-sauna.ru/cto-oznacaet-slovo-koli-v-russkom-yazyke),** где подробно рассматривается слово ***КОЛИ***. Но к сожалению, он скорее **добавил неясности,** чем обозначил значение корня.

**Например:**

****Коли*** – это слово в русском языке **с древними корнями** и разнообразными **значениями**. В зависимости от контекста и употребления, оно может иметь различные **смысловые** оттенки и применяться в разных синонимических значений.*

*Одним из наиболее распространенных значений слова ***коли*** является **устаревшая форма глагола «колоть».** В русском языке эта форма употребляется для выражения процесса рубки или порезки чего-либо острым предметом.*

*Слово «коли» имеет свою **уникальную этимологию** и связано с определенными словами и фразами в русском языке.*

*Одним из слов, близким по значению к «коли», является слово **«ЕСЛИ».** Оба слова имеют **корни в древних славянских языках** и обозначают возможность выполнения условия или события.*

*Интересно отметить, что слово «коли» также имеет корни в **древнегреческом языке** и связано с глаголами, обозначающими возможность или необходимость. Это свидетельствует **о богатой истории** и культурном наследии, связанном с этим словом.*

**ВЫВОД**

**Так что же это за слово такое?** Возможно, следует найти его **изначальный корень** (индоевропейский, вероятно), на основе которого развивались остальные значения.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

"Исследовательская" работа со словарем  [Черных](https://chernykh-etym.narod.ru/)

1. Индоевропейский корень нашелся в слове **колесо**: kol — вращаться, отсюда о.-с. kolo.
2. Слово **сколько**: др.-рус. колико, и.-е. **местоименный** корень ko, как в о.-с. kъto — который, о.-с. формы kolъ и koli.
3. Слово **количество** — калька **с древнегреческого:** сколь многочисленный, сколь значительный, насколько большой.
4. Глагол колоть: о.-с. основа kolti, и.е. корень kel со значением бить, ударять, русск. колоть.

**Вывод по словарю**

Получается, что "коли" имеет **условно-оценочное** значение степени соответствия, близости к названному признаку/суждению (насколько близок).

Тогда, как вариант,  и.-е. **местоименный** корень ko,  о.-с. формы kolъ и koli.

**А круг?** Нужно быть уверенным, что в слове **количество** есть корень kolo — круг. По семантике это похоже — вхождение в круг можно оценить как степень близости. Но полной уверенности нет. Может, кто ещё что подскажет.

**ПРИМЕРЫ**

**[Пословицы](https://vdahl.ru/word/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8/)** у Даля

```
 Нечего на зеркало пенять, коли рожа кривая
 Сама себя кума бьет, коли плохо живет
 Коли быть собаке битой, найдется и палка
 Коли весь мир вздохнет, и до царя дойдет
 Коли взял давно, так и забыто оно
 Коли вожжи порвались, за хвост не управишь
 Коли горько — сдобри медом

 
 Эх, приятель, и ты, видно, горе видал,
 Коли плачешь от песни весёлой!
 Нет, послушай-ка ты, что вот я испытал,
 Так узнаешь о жизни тяжёлой!
                   Иван Никитин. Бурлак
```